# Disable Alt key in Raspbian entirely

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am looking to develop the raspberry pi into something that I would be able to run a free use public web terminal which would be locked to a certain domain. This is for my employer, a township, who wants to set up terminals around the township so that the less fortunate in our community will be able to contact and interact with the various services that the township provides without having to find a way to the Administration center.

I have been able to get most of what I want working, but I want to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on the keyboard. This will stop users from being able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> out of the browser environment, and various other features of LXDE that smart users could use to break my kiosk (like virtual terminals). I thought that I had found the method to do this, with xmodmap, but when I ran this command

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 204 = "
```

Which to my knowledge should set all mappings for the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to nothing, still lets me <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in chromium and other things.

I also attempted to edit my `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` and change the keyboard bindings in it. I was able to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> through that, but when I change or erase other key bindings in there, nothing happens. So I'm trying to figure out other options I have to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on this application. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm pretty sure the detection of CTRL-ALT-DEL is done at a lower level than the X-windows controls.

Comment: It's controlled by the Desktop Manager in linux. In windows it is part of the kernel, not the shell.

Comment: I guess you could always hack the keyboard driver to simply ignore that key...

Comment: That's a better idea than my last resort; cut the traces of the alt key on a keyboard. But luckily I was able to figure out my problem so that doesn't need to happen.

Comment: what if you need access to the terminal to change things what is your back-door?

Answer (score 2):

Soo, I actually just answered my own question. Fixing the problem indeed lies in the `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` file, but I was not doing it right. To set the Ctrl Alt Delete option, you need to change the value between `<command></command>` to `false` (or a program that pops up a finger wag to the user).

The problem was, only four or so of the keys entries have a `<command>` field to them, and all of the other use an `<action="whatever"></action>` field to define the action that is being performed by the key. I was changing the value of "whatever" to false and was under the impression that would have the same effect as changing the command field.

But really, what you need to do is change the value of "whatever" to "Execute", and then nest a set of `<command></command>` with a value set to false and it will set the key's mapping to false. I guess there must be a set of default values that are used to override improper changes to the lxde-rc.xml files, and that's why things kept working after removing the entries.

Comment: I fixed the syntax using back-quote to mark the xml syntax as "code".